# Exporting sikuli unit test data as a report

Tags: unit-testing, sikuli

Is there an automated tool to generate reports containing information about unit tests when using sikuli? The data I want would be things such as pass/fail, a trace to where/why it failed, and a log of events.

Comment: I beleive I may of found the answer.. http://blog.mykhailo.com/2011/02/how-to-sikuli-and-robot-framework.html

Comment: also http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the HTMLTestRunner tool, it was far easier than anything else I found and met the criteria I needed.  (There is also an XML version of this, XMLTestRunner)

```
HTMLTestRunner is an extension to the Python standard library's unittest module. It generates easy to use HTML test reports.
```

http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html

Another useful tool I found was RobotFramework, which can be integrated into Sikuli, but is more complicated and requires alot of research and reading of documentation.